# RTTI on objects in Delphi

Tags: delphi, rtti

I'm trying to parse objects to XML in Delphi, so I read about calling the object's ClassInfo method to get its RTTI info.

The thing is, this apparently only works for TPersistent objects. Otherwise, I have to specifically add a compiler directive {$M+} to the source code for the compiler to generate RTTI info.

So I happily added the directive, only to find that, even if it did return something from the ClassInfo call (it used to return nil), now I cannot retrieve the class' properties, fields or methods from it. It's like it created the object empty.

Any idea what am I missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you put those properties and methods into the `published` section?

Besides that, 'classical' RTTI ($TYPEINFO ON) will only get you information on properties, not on methods. You need 'extended' RTTI ($METHODINFO ON) for those.

Good starting point for extended RTTI: [David Glassborow on extended RTTI](http://hallvards.blogspot.com/2006/05/david-glassborow-on-extended-rtti.html)

(who would believe that just this minute I finished writing some code that uses extended RTTI and decided to browse the Stack Overflow a little:))

Comment: Thanks, that has to be the problem. I was putting the properties on the public, not the published section.
I'll have to wait for monday to try, since I do Delphy at work, and I'm home for the weekend already.

Answer (score 3):

RTTI will only show you **published** properties,etc. - not just public ones.

Try your code with a TObject and see what happens - if that isn't working, *post your code* because not everyone is psychic.

Comment: That was the problem, my properties were just public, not published.
Will try when I'm back at work on monday. Thanks!

Comment: Classic RTTI in delphi shows PUBLISHED properties, "new extended RTTI" can actually see everything, but requires a recent Delphi version (2010/XE or later).

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using the TXMLDocument component?  It will look at your XML and then create a nice unit of Delphi classes that represents your XML file -- makes it really, really easy to read and write XML files.

Comment: TXMLDocument does that? I thought it was the XML Data Binding wizard that did that... ;)

Answer (score 0):

As for the RttiType problem returning only nil, this probably occurs for one reason: in your test, you did not instantiate the class at any time. The compiler, because it never has a reference to this class (because it is not an instance at all), simply removes it from the information as a form of optimization. See the two examples below. The behavior is different when you have the class instantiated at some point in your code or not.

Suppose the following class:

```
type
  TTest = class
  public
    procedure Test;
  end;
```

and the following code below:

```
var
  LContext: TRttiContext;
  LType: TRttiType;
  LTest: TTest;
begin
  LContext := TRttiContext.Create;
  for LType in LContext.GetTypes do
  begin
    if LType.IsInstance then
    begin
      WriteLn(LType.Name);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

so far, TTest class information is not available for use by RTTI. However, when we create at some point, within the application, then a reference is created for it within the compile, which makes this information available:

```
var
  LContext: TRttiContext;
  LType: TRttiType;
  LTest: TTest;
begin
  LTest := TTest.Create; //Here i´m using TTest.
                         //Could be in another part of the program

  LContext := TRttiContext.Create;
  for LType in LContext.GetTypes do
  begin
    if LType.IsInstance then
    begin
      WriteLn(LType.Name);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

At that point, if you use **LContext.FindType ('TTest')**, there will not be a nil return, because the compiler kept reference to the class. This explains the behavior you were having in your tests.